# Get method unauthorized with Jsonwebtoken in nodejs and angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, passport.js, angular-cli

I am building an application using nodejs and angular-cli 
I'm using JsonWebToken to authenticate user account . But it always return Unauthorized 401 . 
Here my code :

// CODE FOR AUTHENTICATE

```
    router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
      const username = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;

      User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
          return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){
            const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
              expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
            });

            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: 'JWT '+token,
              //token:token,
              user: {
                id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email
              }
            });
          } else {
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

---

// GET PROFILE

---

```
    router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({user: req.user});
      });
```

// Get user by Id

```
    module.exports.getUserById=function(id,callback){
        User.findById(id,callback);
    }
```

// Get user by username

```
    module.exports.getUserByUsername=function(username,callback){
        const query={username:username}
        User.findOne(query,callback);
    }
```

// compare password

```
    module.exports.comparePassword=function(candidatePassword,hash,callback){
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword,hash,(err,isMatch)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(null,isMatch);
        });
    }
```

Can you explain me why ?

Comment: How is passport set up? How are you sending the token from the client to the server?

Comment: Here is code for passport 
<code>
module.exports = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
      if(err){
        return done(err, false);
      }

      if(user){
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
}
</code>

Comment: Here is code for passport 
<!-- language: lang-js -->

module.exports = function(passport){ let opts = {}; opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(); opts.secretOrKey = config.secret; passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => { User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => { if(err){ return done(err, false); } if(user){ return done(null, user); } else { return done(null, false); } }); })); }

<!-- end snippet -->

I tested method with post man, I send the token which I got when I log in
but it failed .

Comment: Can you add the code in the comments to the question itself? If you are sending the token as `JWT ey...` to the server you can try changing it to `bearer ey...`. That's the format it expects. If that doesn't work you should try console.logging the request just as it arrives at the server. `req.headers.authorization` is the important part.